# Celery : cannot shutdown celery due to PID changes

Tags: celery, django-celery

I'm using Cerely to manage delayed task on my django project.

I got problem when I tried to shutdown celery as suggested in the **[manual](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/userguide/workers.html#worker-stopping)**.

```
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
   kill: No such process
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}
   28630
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}
   28633
```

**PID continuosly changes** and it makes hard to send killing signal.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

---

**[ Update ]**

django *settings.py*

```
import djcelery

    djcelery.setup_loader()
    BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/' # Using RabbitMQ
    CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1
```

**PID check** (After reboot)

```
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}'
   3243
>> manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
   celery@{some id value}.... ready
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}'
   3285
   3293
   3296
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
   kill: No such process
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}'
   3321
>> ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}'
   3324
```

**Question**

- At least, one celery worker remains even though rebooted. And its PID changes continuously.
- Celery daemon executes two workers at once. How can I fix it to only one worker ?

Comment: It looks like the worker is being restarted. Does it actually work, i.e. execute tasks? If yes, do you run it with `--maxtasksperchild` / [`CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-max-tasks-per-child)?

Comment: Thanks for @VasiliyFaronov. I added more detail description about my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing precisely what you asked for with the [`CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-max-tasks-per-child) setting:

> Maximum number of tasks a pool worker process can execute before it’s replaced with a new one.

Apparently you wanted to run one worker process, but that is controlled by a different setting, namely [`CELERYD_CONCURRENCY`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-concurrency).

So, replace

```
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1
```

with

```
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
```

Comment: I replaced `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` with `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY` as you suggested. But it doesn't changed after restarted. I have no idea.

Comment: Even though I (pip) uninstalled celery, command `ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}'` returns some ID which changes continuously.

Comment: @UKS Oh, I forgot the usual nuisance: that PID you get is the PID of the `grep` process itself. Add `| grep -v grep`, or use `pgrep`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was of help !